# How to show product variation in cloumn instead of row in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to show Woocommerce product attributes and variations in the column.
I'm using [YITH Labels and Colors Variations](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/yith-woocommerce-colors-and-labels-variations/) Plugin. The [live link to my web site](http://entryksag.dk/product/petit-ring/)

My current layout is:

[image: current layout]

The layout which I want to have is:

[image: layout which i want......]

I have tried some custom css code:

```css
.select_box_label.select_box.attribute_pa_size { 
    margin: 50px 30px 0px 0px;
    width:100px;
}

.select_box_colorpicker.select_box.attribute_pa_colors {
    margin: -70px 10px 0px 200px;
    width:70px;
}
```

and the resulting output is:

[image: here]

Is there is any other way to present it in column?

Then please let me know or tell me how to arrange the label at right place.

Comment: Your 3rd link with the result output is missing in your question… you should edit your question to add it please. Additionally we should need a live link to help you. Also it seem that you are using a plugin or custom code for this display, so you better add this information or custom code.

Comment: check third link here https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfzI2.png i cant add it in question as it requires 10 Reputation. Check the link link of the website http://entryksag.dk/product/petit-ring/

Comment: I'm using YITH Labels and Colors Variations Plugin

Comment: As this is a formatted html table you can't make the `<tr>` rows in columns and each row as already 2 `<td>` columns, one is the **label** like "SIZE" and the other the **values** (the swatches)… You should need to edit the plugin files to get the desired html structure output.